# How do I search by multiple keywords when using awk or grep?

Tags: linux, find, grep

I have a collection of files.  I want to search through them all with `grep` to find **all and only** those which contain anywhere within them **both** the strings `keyword1` **and** `keyword2`.

I would also like to know how to do this with awk.

Answer (score 2):

For grep, the pipe symbol separates strings in a combination regexp; on some systems, it may be necessary to use egrep to activate this functionality:

```
[madhatta@anni ~]$ egrep 'exact|obsol' /etc/yum.conf
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
```

I would expect the syntax to be similar for awk.

**Edit:** yup:

```
[madhatta@anni ~]$ awk '/exact|obsol/ {print $1}' /etc/yum.conf
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
```

**Edit 2:**

You have clarified your request, so here's how to do it with grep:

```
grep -l keyword1 * | xargs -d '\n' grep -l keyword2
```

This will search all the files in a given directory (`*`) for keyword1, passing the list of matching files onto the second grep, which will search for the second string, via xargs.  I'm afraid I won't be bothering to do this with `awk` as it's beginning to sound a bit like a homework problem.  If you have a business case for using awk, let us know.

Comment: What I want is not `OR`, but `AND`

Comment: That's an ambiguous question.  Do you want a list of **files** that contain both keywords anywhere, or a list of files that contain both keywords on the same line, or all **lines** that contain both keywords from a single file?

Comment: It's the first case.

Comment: See Edit 2 above; also, I have edited your question to clarify your request.

Answer (score 1):

### Search in one file

Using grep to find lines with either "keyword1" or "keyword2" in the file "myfile.conf":

```
grep -e "keyword1\|keyword2" myfile.conf
```

The escaping of the pipe `|` character with a backslash is at least required in zsh.

### Search in all files in a directory

To search for files containing either "keyword1" or "keyword2" in a directory:

```
grep -r -e "keyword1\|keyword2" /path/to/my/directory
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive search, add the `-i` option as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to search all the files which contains `keyword1` **and** `keyword2` in a specific folder, so, try this:

```
$ find /path/to/folder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li "keyword1" | \
                                    xargs -I '{}' grep -li "keyword2" '{}'
```

- `-print0 | xargs -0` take cares of file names with blank spaces
- `-I` tells `xargs` to replace `'{}'` with the argument list
- `grep -li`  prints file name instead of matching pattern. I use `-i`
  for case insensitive.